# Generic Struct as argument to c++/cli function causes error CS0570 in VS 2015 but not in VS2013

Tags: c#, generics, c++-cli, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

We have a solution that compiles perfectly in VS2013 but fails with a compilation error in VS2015.

The problem has been narrowed down to this:

We have a c# project A which defines a generic struct like this:

```
public struct MyStruct<T>
{

    public MyStruct(T b)
    {
    }
}
```

We have a c++/cli project B which defines a function like this:

```
public ref class Class1
{

public:
    void BadMethod(MyStruct<int> ^){};
};
```

And finally I have a c# command line project C referencing Project A and B and trying to call BadMethod:

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c = new Class1();
            var s = new MyStruct<int>(0);

            c.BadMethod(s);
        }
    }
```

In Visual Studio 2013 (and older) this compiles without any issues, in Visual Studio 2015 however we get:

```
application\Program.cs(18,15,18,24): error CS0570: 'Class1.BadMethod(?)' is not supported by the language
```

I have tried compiling the c++/cli project using the Visual Studio 2015 toolset but the error remains.

Using a generic class instead of a struct seems to work.

Comment: This sounds similar to https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4163.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   void BadMethod(MyStruct<int> ^){};
```

Fairly remarkable how often a new VS version gets blamed for a programming bug.  The MyStruct type is a *value type*.  But yet you declared the argument type as a reference type variable.  Note the ^ hat you used.

Somewhat unfortunately, the C++/CLI compiler *does* support this.  And so does the CLR, the value must be *boxed* first before it can be passed to the method call.  Very inefficient, the point of using value types is always to *avoid* boxing.  There is however no type annotation available in the CLR for such a boxed type, it becomes System::ValueType in the metadata.  With a runtime check that the value is of the expected type.  More inefficiency, this adds up to big bucks.

The C# language does not support this at all and spits bullets at having to box the value.  Without any way to check that it is the *required* value type, it takes static type checking very seriously.

The fix is very simple, just omit `^` so the argument is passed by value and doesn't have to be boxed.  If you meant to pass the value by reference, not clear from the question, then you must use `%` instead.

And probably a good idea to check the rest of your code, C++/CLI makes it far too easy to fumble this and lose gobs of perf without any peep from the compiler.  Apply the simple rule, variables of a value type must *never* have the hat.  Variables of a reference type should always have the hat unless stack semantics (using statement in C#) is intended.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, makes it a lot easier for me in discussions with developers.